# MySQL: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger #1415

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have created the following trigger with phpmyadmin on xampp for windows

```
CREATE TRIGGER strip_ud_in BEFORE INSERT ON ci_sessions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'"','&#34');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,':','&#58');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,';','&#59');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'{','&#123');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'}','&#125');
END
```

and I got the error on the first try to insert on the ci_sessions table by calling a controller with url from my chrome browser

> Error Number: 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Comment: Do you have any other triggers on ci_sessions?

Comment: I did try to replace  NEW.user_data with @ud variable and only kept the last. Did not work either.

Comment: zedfoxus I do actually. Is that a problem?!

Comment: The problem can be on those other trigger(s). This trigger has no problems from what I can say.

Comment: It is  tricky. Because it is the only trigger for this event "before insert".

Comment: That's okay. You should definitely check out the other triggers though. Let me add an example you can test out to see for yourself that this trigger is just fine!

Comment: Were you able to find out the problem with your trigger(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this trigger has anything to do with the error. Let's take an example to help take attention off of this trigger.

```
-- create a dummy table
create table ci_sessions_test (user_data varchar(100));

-- create the same kind of trigger on this dummy table
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER strip_ud_in_ci_sessions_test BEFORE INSERT ON ci_sessions_test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'"','&#34');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,':','&#58');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,';','&#59');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'{','&#123');
SET NEW.user_data = REPLACE(NEW.user_data,'}','&#125');
END //

delimiter ;
```

Add some data now. Notice the results appear just fine.

```
insert into ci_sessions_test values ('test'), ('testing;');

select * from ci_sessions_test;

Results:
user_data
----------
test
testing&#59
```

This indicates that the trigger functions appropriately without causing errors. It also indicates that if there are other triggers on this table, they could possibly be a cause for the error. In those triggers, make sure that if you are not using `SELECT fields FROM ...`. If you are using something like that, you might need to change them to `SELECT fields INTO localvariablename FROM ...`.